# How to run Ubuntu utils from USB?

Tags: linux

How can I extract OS utils/commands like "ps,who,lsof,netstat..." and run it from my USB? I need to extract these tools from clean OS linux and run it on infected computer.

I tried just copy these tools from /bin but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need static linked binaries without external libraries (/lib/*.so files)
A major tool for many commands on embedded devices is: busybox
You probably find a static version for your os on: busybox.net
My busybox...

```
busybox
BusyBox v1.30.0 (2018-12-30 22:25:27 CET) multi-call binary.
BusyBox is copyrighted by many authors between 1998-2015.
Licensed under GPLv2. See source distribution for detailed
copyright notices.

Usage: busybox [function [arguments]...]
   or: busybox --list[-full]
   or: busybox --show SCRIPT
   or: busybox --install [-s] [DIR]
   or: function [arguments]...

    BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix
    utilities into a single executable.  Most people will create a
    link to busybox for each function they wish to use and BusyBox
    will act like whatever it was invoked as.

Currently defined functions:
    [, [[, acpid, add-shell, addgroup, adduser, adjtimex, ar, arch, arp, arping, ash, awk, base64, basename, bc, blkdiscard, blkid,
    blockdev, bootchartd, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat, bzip2, cal, cat, chat, chattr, chgrp, chmod, chown, chpasswd, chpst, chroot, chrt,
    chvt, cksum, clear, cmp, comm, conspy, cp, cpio, crond, crontab, cryptpw, cttyhack, cut, date, dc, dd, deallocvt, delgroup,
    deluser, depmod, devmem, df, dhcprelay, diff, dirname, dmesg, dnsd, dnsdomainname, dos2unix, dpkg, dpkg-deb, du, dumpkmap,
    dumpleases, echo, ed, egrep, eject, env, envdir, envuidgid, expand, expr, factor, fakeidentd, false, fatattr, fbset, fbsplash,
    fdflush, fdformat, fdisk, fgconsole, fgrep, find, findfs, flash_eraseall, flash_lock, flash_unlock, flashcp, flock, fold, free,
    freeramdisk, fsck, fsck.minix, fsfreeze, fstrim, fsync, ftpd, ftpget, ftpput, fuser, getopt, getty, grep, groups, gunzip, gzip,
    halt, hd, hdparm, head, hexdump, hexedit, hostid, hostname, httpd, hush, hwclock, i2cdetect, i2cdump, i2cget, i2cset, id,
    ifconfig, ifenslave, ifplugd, inetd, init, inotifyd, insmod, install, ionice, iostat, ip, ipaddr, ipcalc, ipcrm, ipcs, iplink,
    ipneigh, iproute, iprule, iptunnel, kbd_mode, kill, killall, killall5, klogd, last, less, link, linux32, linux64, linuxrc, ln,
    loadfont, loadkmap, logger, login, logname, losetup, lpd, lpq, lpr, ls, lsattr, lsmod, lsof, lspci, lsscsi, lsusb, lzcat, lzma,
    lzop, lzopcat, makedevs, makemime, man, md5sum, mdev, mesg, microcom, mkdir, mkdosfs, mke2fs, mkfifo, mkfs.ext2, mkfs.minix,
    mkfs.vfat, mknod, mkpasswd, mkswap, mktemp, modinfo, modprobe, more, mount, mountpoint, mpstat, mt, mv, nameif, nbd-client, nc,
    netstat, nice, nl, nmeter, nohup, nologin, nproc, ntpd, nuke, od, openvt, partprobe, passwd, paste, patch, pgrep, pidof, ping,
    ping6, pipe_progress, pivot_root, pkill, pmap, popmaildir, poweroff, powertop, printenv, printf, ps, pscan, pstree, pwd, pwdx,
    raidautorun, rdate, rdev, readlink, readprofile, realpath, reboot, reformime, remove-shell, renice, reset, resize, resume, rev,
    rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, rpm, rpm2cpio, rtcwake, run-init, run-parts, runlevel, runsv, runsvdir, rx, script, scriptreplay, sed,
    sendmail, seq, setarch, setconsole, setfattr, setfont, setkeycodes, setlogcons, setpriv, setserial, setsid, setuidgid, sh,
    sha1sum, sha256sum, sha3sum, sha512sum, showkey, shred, shuf, slattach, sleep, smemcap, softlimit, sort, split, ssl_client,
    start-stop-daemon, stat, strings, stty, su, sulogin, sum, sv, svc, svlogd, svok, swapoff, swapon, switch_root, sync, sysctl,
    syslogd, tac, tail, tar, taskset, tc, tcpsvd, tee, telnet, telnetd, test, tftp, tftpd, time, timeout, top, touch, tr,
    traceroute, traceroute6, true, truncate, tty, ttysize, tunctl, tune2fs, ubiattach, ubidetach, ubimkvol, ubirename, ubirmvol,
    ubirsvol, ubiupdatevol, udhcpc, udhcpd, udpsvd, uevent, umount, uname, uncompress, unexpand, uniq, unix2dos, unlink, unlzma,
    unlzop, unxz, unzip, uptime, users, usleep, uudecode, uuencode, vconfig, vi, vlock, volname, w, wall, watch, watchdog, wc, wget,
    which, who, whoami, whois, xargs, xxd, xz, xzcat, yes, zcat, zcip
```